# Retuning Empty List After Call ServiceClass Method from Testing Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

Retuning Empty List after call  getStudentDetails()
I have written one Studentservice class and one StudentRepo Interface and want to junit test of service class using junit5 with mockito.

Expecting Size of List is 2 but return 0.
please follow below code for reference

Student Service Class

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepo studentRepo;
    
    public List<Student> getStudentDetails(){
        
        List<Student> students = studentRepo.findAll();
        
        for(Student student : students) {
            student.setMarks(50);
        }
        return students;
    }
}
```

StudentService testing class

```
@WebMvcTest(StudentService.class)
public class StudentServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    StudentRepo studentRepoMock;
    
    @Mock
    StudentService studentServiceMock;
    
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        
        
        when(studentRepoMock.findAll()).thenReturn(
                Arrays.asList(new Student(1,"abc"),
                (new Student(2,"def"))
                ));
        
        
        List<Student> student=studentServiceMock.getStudentDetails();  //return empty List
        
        
        verify(studentServiceMock, Mockito.times(1)).getStudentDetails(); /*it's working*/

        System.out.println(student.size());  
        
        //assertEquals(50,student.get(0).getMarks());
        //assertEquals(50,student.get(1).getMarks());
        
    }   
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mocked both the repository and the service. You are never calling any real functionality that way. If you want to test `StudentService`, you have to let Spring at least instantiate it by replacing `@Mock` with `@Autowired` on the `StudentService`.